# Execute an exe(Inside Project structure) in Electron

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

While in developing mode, executing the exe is working well.

My code to launch the exe is

```
function LaunchExe() {
        var child = require('child_process').execFile;
        var executablePath = 'DemoExe/Sample.exe';
        var parameters = ['Hai', 'Test', 'Dat'];
        child(executablePath, parameters, function (err, data) {
            console.log(err)
            console.log(data.toString());
        });
}
```

But after packaging the Electron app, I can't launch the exe.

The command I use to build the exe is

```
electron-packager . --asar
```

Error code

```
 Error: spawn DemoExe/Sample.exe ENOENT
     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:232)
     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407)
     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63)
```

*Regards.*

Comment: Seems like the executable isn't found. Is it present in the package folder?

Comment: After packaging i got two files,1.app.asar, 2.electron.asar

Comment: Try to add `./` before the path, so became `var executablePath = './DemoExe/Sample.exe';`

Comment: @LeonardoBuscemi i have tried that but unfortunately not executing

Comment: So use `var executablePath = path.join("./", "DemoExe", "Sample.exe")`

Comment: i will try and let you know. thanks

Comment: Unfortunately not working same error continuous .

Comment: My last attempt: try `path.join(__dirname, "DemoExe", "Sample.exe")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got to work with following steps,

1.package the Electron app using command

> electron-packager .

2.Path to exe

> path.join(__dirname, "DemoExe", "Sample.exe")

Answer (score 1):

Is your project with angular?

Maybe this can help, but I had problems too with electron-packager.

So I suggest you to use electron builder : https://www.electron.build

Fist you need to add a file at root called **electron-builder.json** and it shoul'd contain the following (you need to update productname and icons location):

```
{
  "productName": "projectname",
  "appId": "org.project.projectname",
  "artifactName": "${productName}-setup-${version}.${ext}",
  "directories": {
    "output": "builds/"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist/",
    "node_modules/",
    "package.json",
    "**/*",
    "!**/*.ts",
    "!*.code-workspace",
    "!package-lock.json",
    "!src/",
    "!e2e/",
    "!hooks/",
    "!angular.json",
    "!_config.yml",
    "!karma.conf.js",
    "!tsconfig.json",
    "!tslint.json"
  ],
  "nsis": {
    "oneClick": false,
    "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true
  },
  "mac": {
    "icon": "src/favicon.ico"
  },
  "win": {
    "icon": "src/favicon.ico"
  },
  "linux": {
    "icon": "src/favicon.png"
  }
}
```

Then, you need to add those scripts to your **package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- -c production",
    "package:windows": "npm run build:prod && electron-builder build --windows"
}
```

can compile the executable with

> npm run package:windows

Also, don't forget to add electron builder into your dev dependencies :

> yarn add electron-builder --dev

the executable with be located into **/builds**

Comment: I'm getting this error while executing *npm run package:windows* npm ERR! missing script: build

Comment: Also I'm not using  angular.

Comment: npm run build:prod command in package:windows script is for angular project, can remove